# Hudson doesn't checkout using symlinks when using SVN (Subversion)

Tags: svn, hudson, symlink, svn-checkout

The problem is that when Hudson checks out the files, it doesn't use symlinks. I've tried the svn13 and svn14 plug ins, but neither worked.

Comment: Be careful with symlinks in repositories. I opened up a bug ticket in JIRA for hudson:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9856

Essentially, symlinks linking outside your check-out directory can cause the files/folders to be deleted when Jenkins cleans the workspace.

Comment: Resolved this problem as a part of 1.30 as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In linux, edit your /etc/init.d/hudson script file:

Look for a line that looks like:

```
$SU $HUDSON_USER --shell=/bin/bash -c "$DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS -- $JAVA $JAVA_ARGS  -jar $HUDSON_WAR $HUDSON_ARGS" || return 2
```

Change it to:

```
$SU $HUDSON_USER --shell=/bin/bash -c "$DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS -- $JAVA $JAVA_ARGS -Dsvnkit.symlinks=true -jar $HUDSON_WAR $HUDSON_ARGS" || return 2
```

Save the file and type:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hudson stop
sudo /etc/init.d/hudson start
```

In summary, you're essentially looking to pass JAVA -Dsvnkit.symlinks=true so that symlinks are resolved to folders instead of a file.

Answer (score 2):

In CentOS, the line you should change reads:

```
JAVA_CMD="$JENKINS_JAVA_CMD $JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS -DJENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME -jar $JENKINS_WAR"
```

Change it to:

```
JAVA_CMD="$JENKINS_JAVA_CMD $JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS -DJENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME -Dsvnkit.symlinks=true -jar $JENKINS_WAR"
```

And restart jenkins

Comment: Thanks for posting the discrepancy between distributions!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which version of the subversion plugin you've tried, but as of subversion plugin 1.30 it works out of the box.

I guess SVNKit at some point change the default from doing symlink by default, and Jenkins benefited from it.

Comment: Yah, come to think of it, when I installed it on a Fedora box back in like march or may, I didn't need to do it that time. Good thing to point out to those using more current versions that doing this isn't really necessary anymore.

Comment: I'm running jenkins latest version on CentOS and it still doesn't work without adding svnkit.symlinks=true option

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit this setting per slave node, this worked for me:

From Jenkins UI:

1. Disconnect node
2. Click on slave node, Under Configure -> Advanced -> JVM Options:
3. Add line: Dsvnkit.symlinks=true
4. Relaunch slave