# Configure Subversion plugin in Jenkins to use 1.6 working copy

Tags: svn, jenkins, svnkit

I use the Jenkins Subversion plugin to checkout a working copy in Jenkins. A separate SVN client is used to extract some information from this working copy (which branch was used, which revision, etc.).

The Subversion plugin creates a 1.7 working copy, which the other client can't handle (it is 1.6). **Is there a way to configure the Subversion plugin to checkout a 1.6 working copy?**

This question lists a way to configure the Subversion plugin: [Hudson doesn't checkout using symlinks when using SVN (Subversion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417869/hudson-doesnt-checkout-using-symlinks-when-using-svn-subversion)
So I started looking for all configuration options, and ended up on this page: http://svnkit.com/kb/user-guide-config-settings.html , but it is really incomplete.

Also I found this: http://wiki.svnkit.com/SVNKit_FAQ#Q:_Can_the_current_SVNKit_version_be_forced_to_create_pre-1.5_format_working_copies.3F , except that that property is ignored for new directories.

I cannot use Jenkins variables to extract the branch and revision information, because the same script must also be able to run outside Jenkins. Updating the separate client is also not possible, because we are working with 'frozen' software on build systems. If all else fails I could downgrade Jenkins, but that's not preferred.

Comment: I didn't work with jenkins, but SVNKit will create 1.6 working copies if you set java property "svnkit.wc.17" to "false" (default: "true").

Comment: @DmitryPavlenko Thank you so much. The newer versions of Jenkins/Hudson come with this svnkit version that they use for checkout. However, when performing a maven release, Jenkins/Hudson uses the **linux svn** client, which in our case was 1.6.6

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On main Jenkins configurations page (`http:/<jenkins_server>/configure`) search for *Subversion Workspace Version* and set it to appropriate value (1.6).

Comment: This is indeed the answer to my question. It did not fix the problem though, as it was _already_ set to 1.6. I'll leave this question as is and flag it as answered.

Comment: Wait, if it did not fix your problem, why are you accepting the answer?

Comment: Because I hadn't analyzed my problem correctly, I asked the wrong question. You did provide the answer to the question, therefore deserving the green check mark.